# Proving that an operator is compact.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $(\lambda_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N^{*}}}$ be a sequence of real numbers converging to $0$ and let $(u_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N^{*}}}$ be an orthonormal family in a Hilbert space $H$. Define $T:H \rightarrow H$ by $$T(u) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lambda_{k}\langle u,u_{k}\rangle u_{k}$$

Prove that $T$ is compact. could anyone help me please in doing so?

Thanks!

Comment: Every continuous finite-rank operator is compact. The norm-limit of compact operators is compact. This operator is the norm-limit of finite-rank operators.

Comment: Why this operator is the norm-limit of finite-rank operators? @DanielFischer

Comment: Because $\lambda_k \to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I ask you to prove that $T$ is compact if and only if it satisfies the following: if $\{v\}, (v_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq H$ and $v_{n} \rightharpoonup v$, then $T(v_{n}) \to T(v)$.  Here and henceforth the notation "$x_{n} \rightharpoonup x$" reads "$(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges weakly to $x$."

Now suppose $\{v\}, (v_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq H$ and $v_{n} \rightharpoonup v$.  Recall that $v_{n} \rightharpoonup v$ implies the sequence $(\|v_{n}\|)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded.  Hence the sequence $(\|v_{n} - v\|)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, by the triangle inequality.  It remains to prove $0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \|T(v_{n} - v)\|$.  To do this, fix $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and observe
\begin{align*}
\|T(v_{n} - v)\|^{2} &= \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \lambda_{j}^{2} |\langle v_{n} - v, u_{j} \rangle|^{2} \\
&\leq \sum_{j = 1}^{N} \lambda_{j}^{2} |\langle v_{n} - v, u_{j} \rangle|^{2} + \sup\{\lambda_{j}^{2} \, \mid \, j \geq N + 1\} \|v_{n} - v\|^{2}.
\end{align*}
Since $v_{n} \rightharpoonup v$, we obtain
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \|T(v_{n} - v)\|^{2} \leq \sup\{\lambda_{j}^{2} \, \mid \, j \geq N + 1\} \cdot \sup \{\|v_{n} - v\|^{2} \, \mid \, n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$
From this, conclude that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \|T(v_{n} - v)\|^{2} = 0$.

**Edit:**  I'll do this without weak convergence.  To show that $T$ is a compact operator, it suffices to show that if $(v_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence, then $(T(v_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a subsequence that converges in norm.  Thus, assume $(v_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence.

Step 1: Observe that, for each $j \in \mathbb{N}$, the sequence $(\langle v_{n},u_{j} \rangle)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded.  Thus, there is a subsequence $(n^{(j)}_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $(\langle v_{n^{(j)}_{k}}, u_{j} \rangle)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence.  (This follows from the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem.)

Step 2: By Step 1, we can apply a diagonalization argument to obtain a subsequence $(n^{*}_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that
$$\forall j \in \mathbb{N} \quad (\langle v_{n^{*}_{k}}, u_{j} \rangle)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \, \, \text{is a Cauchy sequence.}$$

Step 3: For now, $N$ denotes a positive integer to be determined.  If $k, \ell \in \mathbb{N}$, then
\begin{align*}
\|T(v_{n^{*}_{k}} - v_{n^{*}_{\ell}})\|^{2} \leq \sum_{j = 1}^{N} \lambda_{j}^{2} |\langle v_{n^{*}_{k}} - v_{n^{*}_{\ell}}, u_{j} \rangle|^{2} + \sup\{\lambda_{j}^{2} \, \mid \, j \geq N + 1\} \cdot \|v_{n^{*}_{k}} - v_{n^{*}_{\ell}}\|^{2}
\end{align*}
Now pick $\epsilon > 0$.  First, choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$\sup\{\lambda_{j}^{2} \, \mid \, j \geq N +1\} < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \cdot \left(\sup\{\|v_{n} - v_{m}\|^{2} \, \mid \, n, m \in \mathbb{N}\}\right)^{-1}.$$
This is possible since $\lim_{j \to \infty} \lambda_{j}^{2} = 0$.
For each $j \in \{1,2,\dots,N\}$, there is a $M_{j} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|\langle v_{n^{*}_{k}} - v^{n^{*}_{\ell}}, u_{j} \rangle|^{2} < \frac{\epsilon}{2N}$ if $k, \ell \geq M_{j}$.  Therefore, our previous work and choice of the integers $N,M_{1},\dots,M_{n}$ shows that if $k, \ell \geq \max\{M_{1},\dots,M_{N}\}$, then 
$$\|T(v_{n^{*}_{k}} - v_{n^{*}_{\ell}})\|^{2} < \epsilon.$$  This proves $(T(v_{n^{*}_{k}}))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence.  $H$ is complete so it must converge.  Therefore, $(T(v_{n^{*}_{k}}))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a convergent subsequence of $(T(v_{n}))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, which is what we sought to find.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your definition of compact operator.  If $v_n \to v$ then the identity operator satisfies $Iv_n = v_n \to v = Iv$, but $I$ is certainly not compact!  Enlighten me, por favor?

Comment: @RobertLewis The answer used $v_n \rightharpoonup v$, which is a common notation for weak convergence. So the characterisation is that (in this setting, for Banach spaces) an operator is compact if and only if it is completely continuous [that is, maps weakly convergent sequences to convergent sequences].

Comment: Could we prove it without weak convergence?

Comment: @DanielFischer:  OK, wasn't used to that notation.  Thanks for clarifying,

Comment: @Intuition, is there a reason you want to avoid using weak convergence?  We could modify the proof I gave to show that $T$ maps bounded sets to relatively compact sets, but weak convergence is pretty convenient here.

Comment: because we did not study weak convergence formally although I have an idea about it. what do you mean by relatively compact sets?

Comment: OK, I updated the post with a slightly altered proof.  Let me know if it's readable.